# How to group legend labels in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have datasets of different sizes that I want to include in a plot using `scatter` with a `colorbar` from `matplotlib`. In order to avoid having too many items in the legend (and not run out of marker-types), I would like to categorize all legend items into `lab_a`, `lab_b`, and `lab_c` occurring only one time each.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mplcol

data_ax = np.random.rand(10,4)
data_bx = np.random.rand(7, 1)
data_cx = [np.random.rand(6,1), np.random.rand(5,1), np.random.rand(8,1)]

data_ay = np.random.rand(10,4)
data_by = np.random.rand(7, 1)
data_cy = [np.random.rand(6,1), np.random.rand(5,1), np.random.rand(8,1)]

data_az = np.random.rand(10,4)
data_bz = np.random.rand(7, 1)
data_cz = [np.random.rand(6,1), np.random.rand(5,1), np.random.rand(8,1)]

lab_a = 'Data A'
lab_b = 'Data B'
lab_c = 'Data C'

mrk_a = 'o'
mrk_b = 's'
mrk_c = 'D'

cm = plt.cm.get_cmap('viridis')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for x, y, z, l, m in zip([data_ax, data_bx, data_cx], [data_ay, data_by, data_cy], [data_az, data_bz, data_cz], [lab_a, lab_b, lab_c], [mrk_a, mrk_b, mrk_c]):
    #sc = ax.scatter(x, y, c=z, label=l, marker=m, cmap=cm, norm=mplcol.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=1))
    for x2, y2, z2 in zip(x, y, z):
        sc = ax.scatter(x2, y2, c=z2, label=l, marker=m, cmap=cm, norm=mplcol.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=1))

ax1.legend()

cb = plt.colorbar(sc)

plt.show()
```

When I run the code above, the labels in the legend repeat themselves. If I run only one loop (i.e. `#sc`), `data_cx`, `data_cy`, and `data_cz` generate a problem because the shape is not consistent and an error arises:

```
ValueError: 'c' argument must either be valid as mpl color(s) or as numbers to be mapped to colors.
```

- Is there a way to group the labels so that I can run both loops and the legend only contains singular `lab_a`, `lab_b`, and `lab_c`?
- Is there perhaps a better way to group the labels that I am unaware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to only give a label to scatter the first time in the loop:

```py
for x, y, z, l, m in zip([data_ax, data_bx, data_cx], [data_ay, data_by, data_cy], [data_az, data_bz, data_cz], [lab_a, lab_b, lab_c], [mrk_a, mrk_b, mrk_c]):
    for ind, (x2, y2, z2) in enumerate(zip(x, y, z)):
        sc = ax.scatter(x2, y2, c=z2, label=l if ind == 0 else None,
                        marker=m, cmap=cm, norm=mplcol.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=1))
```

Another approach is to convert all data to np.arrays (data_cx etc. is now a list of np.arrays), and then use `ravel` (or `flatten`) from numpy.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mplcol

data_ax = np.random.rand(10,4)
data_bx = np.random.rand(7, 1)
data_cx = np.concatenate([np.random.rand(6,1), np.random.rand(5,1), np.random.rand(8,1)])

data_ay = np.random.rand(10,4)
data_by = np.random.rand(7, 1)
data_cy = np.concatenate( [np.random.rand(6,1), np.random.rand(5,1), np.random.rand(8,1)])

data_az = np.random.rand(10,4)
data_bz = np.random.rand(7, 1)
data_cz = np.concatenate( [np.random.rand(6,1), np.random.rand(5,1), np.random.rand(8,1)])

lab_a = 'Data A'
lab_b = 'Data B'
lab_c = 'Data C'

mrk_a = 'o'
mrk_b = 's'
mrk_c = 'D'

cm = plt.cm.get_cmap('viridis')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for x, y, z, l, m in zip([data_ax, data_bx, data_cx], [data_ay, data_by, data_cy], [data_az, data_bz, data_cz], [lab_a, lab_b, lab_c], [mrk_a, mrk_b, mrk_c]):
    sc = ax.scatter(x.ravel(), y.ravel(), c=z.ravel(), label=l, marker=m, cmap=cm, norm=mplcol.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=1))
ax.legend()

cb = plt.colorbar(sc)

plt.show()
```